# JPA Query for a simple SQL query

Tags: sql, jpa

SELECT * FROM tableA a
WHERE id IN (
SELECT DISTINCT extId
FROM tableB
);

Comment: We need more information to be able to resolve your issue. What are your entities like? What have you attempted? What errors or unexpected results are you getting?

Comment: This is not according to website standards, more information is needed on what are you trying to achieve. What problem are you facing!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT a FROM tableA a WHERE id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT extId
FROM tableB ")
```